# Editing in first post review not worthwhile, someone else takes the review point

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

I just spent some time (a minute or so) to edit a new users first question. I found the question through the First Posts review queue. After editing the question someone else had already reviewed the same post and the "I'm Done" button was gone so I didn't get any review credit for my work.

This behavior of the review system rewards faster reviews and discourages real work. I suggest that the system is changed so that posts are **locked to one reviewer at a time**, or so that **all the people who saw the review task is able to get it counted** towards their badges.