# Is the new review function fulfilling its purpose?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

**The problem**

Since Sunday the new review queue has less than 10 posts in average in the First Posts and Late Answers.

I noted that sometimes reviews enter in a "fast mode" where people do fast things (like upvoting/downvoting or small edits) and ignore some things that should be fixed like:

1. Extremely poor English (both grammar, repeated information and punctuation)
2. Extremely bad code format (e.g. using `>` instead of four spaces, too many backspaces that wrap the code in a horizontal scroll, etc.)
3. Or even wrong/incomplete tags

The last case I saw was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12778865/revisions). I have started my edit before the Yaroslav's edit was finished, but despite this poor formatting (even with text at the end that didn't belong to the code) this post was reviewed by another user without a single change in the post (Yaroslav didn't use the "review" function, probably saw this post and just edited it).

**A suggestion**

The way I see this could be improved by doing some sort of checklist that transfers the responsibility to the user that is reviewing. Before someone could do "I'm done" it would have to check a list like:

1. Does this user deserve an upvote/downvote?
2. Does this post need more editing?

Etc.

Note that if I edited a post then the checklist could be automatically selected (and I could deselected if I believe by editing wasn't enough).

If some of the checklists items weren't set to check then the post would go back into the review queue and someone could review the rest (and see the current "status" of the checklist).

Comment: What does "oist" mean?

Comment: Was going to fix that. It means nothing :p

Comment: I've been seeing more of this now that the queues are scarce. It wasn't so much of a problem, seems to me, when there were plenty of items there.

Comment: @ChrisF [Okinawa Institute of Science and Technology](http://www.oist.jp/)

Comment: Related: [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything) and [Editing in first post review not worthwhile, someone else takes the review point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149655/editing-in-first-post-review-not-worthwhile-someone-else-takes-the-review-point).

Comment: @ЯegDwight Actually some suggestions (like letting multiple reviews happen) are part of my check-list suggestion. Sorry for missing those related questions.

Comment: [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1199684/devils-child) for one, is simply going through the queue up-voting everything for the credit.

Comment: What impresses me are the users that have more than 4k rep doing this. This is actually crazy.

Also I don't believe that this question is an "exact" duplicate, but as long as this gets solved I don't care how you treat the new threads about this subject.